# Update query for cassandra using variable in python

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to run update query with variables. I am using `casandra-driver` as guided in datastax website.I am  using following script to connect cluster and update the values in table `ct_table`.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('ct_keyspace')
a=90
session.execute("update ct_table set value=%d where attribute='CT'",(int(a)))
result = session.execute("select * from ct_table where attribute='CT'")[0]
print result.attribute, result.value
```

I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connection.py", line 7, in <module>
    session.execute("update ct_table set value=%d where attribute='CT'",(a))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1998, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2035, in execute_async
    future = self._create_response_future(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2095, in _create_response_future
    query_string = bind_params(query_string, parameters, self.encoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 823, in bind_params
    return query % tuple(encoder.cql_encode_all_types(v) for v in params)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My table looks like this:

```
cqlsh:ct_keyspace> describe ct_table

CREATE TABLE ct_keyspace.ct_table (
    attribute text PRIMARY KEY,
    value int
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

`value`  is defined in the table as `int` . I suspect I am formatting the string for update query incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session.execute("update ct_table set value=%d where attribute='CT'",(int(a)))
```

should be

```
session.execute("update ct_table set value=%s where attribute='CT'", (a,))
```

We're specifying the bind marker as `%s` and passing a *tuple* for the parameter list. Without the trailing comma, it's just a value.

see also: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries

> Note that you should use %s for all types of arguments, not just strings